# Render & animate SVG from file that already includes animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, less

I'm working on a reactjs web application. I have an **svg** spinner file that already include the animations. I'm wondering if there is a way that i can render it (including the animation) on rectjs. I'm already rendering svg images, but when i use the same clase that i have for this nothing is rendered. I assume that is because the animation.

There is a way to "**extract**" the animation from the svg and transform it into a **keyframes**?

This is the svg file:

```html
<svg width='48px' height='48px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="uil-default">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(0 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-1s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(25.714285714285715 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.9285714285714286s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(51.42857142857143 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.8571428571428571s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(77.14285714285714 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.7857142857142857s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(102.85714285714286 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.7142857142857143s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(128.57142857142858 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.6428571428571429s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(154.28571428571428 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.5714285714285714s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(180 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.5s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(205.71428571428572 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.42857142857142855s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(231.42857142857142 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.35714285714285715s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(257.14285714285717 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.2857142857142857s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(282.85714285714283 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.21428571428571427s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(308.57142857142856 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.14285714285714285s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
  <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(334.2857142857143 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
    <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-0.07142857142857142s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow what you mean by 'extract', but note React has support for SVG:

Definition:

```
const Spinner = () => (
  <svg width='48px' height='48px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" className="uil-default">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" className ="bk" />
    <rect  x='47' y='40' width='6' height='20' rx='3' ry='3' fill='#000000' transform='rotate(0 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>
      <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='-1s' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
    </rect>
  ...
  </svg>);
```

Then use like this in your React app:

```
<Spinner />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple css solution that might work for you.

This solution is extracted from  [loading](https://loading.io/css/)

```css
.lds-spinner {
  color: official;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.lds-spinner div {
  transform-origin: 32px 32px;
  animation: lds-spinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}
.lds-spinner div:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 29px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: black;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
@keyframes lds-spinner {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```